# R: Convert email name to proper email address

Tags: r

Say I have dataset with two variable. Variable "To" is a mix of name and email address.

```
                 From           To
1     bob.a@mail1.com       d,alan
2 carolyn.b@mail2.com       c,chris
3   chris.c@mail3.com       b,carolyn
4    alan.d@mail4.com       bob.a@mail1.com
```

I want to convert the name in variable "To" to the proper email address as shown in variable "From". for example: create a new variable "To_email" with 1st obs as  alan.d@mail4.com

How to process it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
t <- read.table(text='                 From           To
1     bob.a@mail1.com       d,alan
2 carolyn.b@mail2.com       c,chris
3   chris.c@mail3.com       b,carolyn
4    alan.d@mail4.com       bob.a@mail1.com')

t$FromName <- sub('@.*', '', t$From)
t$ToName <- sub('@.*', '', sub('(.*),(.*)', '\\2.\\1', t$To))
merge(data.frame(Name=t$ToName), data.frame(Name=t$FromName, Email=t$From), by='Name', sort=F)

       Name               Email
1    alan.d    alan.d@mail4.com
2   chris.c   chris.c@mail3.com
3 carolyn.b carolyn.b@mail2.com
4     bob.a     bob.a@mail1.com
```